# How to hide the three-dot dropdown menu on a Vega chart?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

I have a simple chart embedded in my website. Using the vega-lite spec v5. Here's an example:

[image: chart with vega menu]

The circle with three dots triggers a drop-down menu with some actions, including opening the chart in an online vega editor. I don't want to expose these actions to the end user.

How can I disable the menu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called the "actions" menu, and it can be controlled via the `actions` option in the `vegaEmbed` call used to display the chart.

You can hide the menu by setting `actions: false`; it would look something like this:

```
<div id="vis"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spec = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-lite/master/examples/specs/bar.vl.json";
  vegaEmbed('#vis', spec, {"actions": false});
</script>
```

More information on available options can be found at https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Knowing the right terms to search for is key!

Answer (score 0):

If you use React you can add `actions={false}` to remove it

```
<VegaLite spec={spec} actions={false} />
```